# Positioning a sprite at (0, 0) places the sprite off screen by a few pixels

Tags: c++, sfml

When I position a sprite at 0, 0 (top left corner of the screen) it doesn't show. It's off screen by a few pixels. Here is a sample of my code.

```
Sprite s;
Texture t;

t.loadFromFile("Tiles.png");
t.setSmooth(false);

s.setTexture(t);
s.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));

s.setPosition(0, 0);

window.draw(s);

window.display();
```

If I add

```
Style::None
```

to my RenderWindow, then the sprite is positioned properly at the top left of the screen.

Is there a way to position sprites ignoring the windows title bar? Or another way to fix this issue? The only way I can seem to get the sprite positioned correctly is if I guess how many pixels off it is and manually add an offset to the sprites position, but this is a very bad way of doing it and I can't get it positioned perfectly.  If I set the position to (11, 64), the sprite is at about the top left of the screen.

Edit: Here is a full example piece of code I used to recreate the issue:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

const int WIDTH = 1000;
const int HEIGHT = 1000;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "Window", Style::Titlebar | Style::Close);

    RectangleShape square(Vector2f(100.f, 100.f));
    square.setFillColor(Color::Red);
    square.setPosition(0, 0);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event windowEvent;

        while (window.pollEvent(windowEvent))
        {
            if (windowEvent.type == Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear(Color::White);
        window.draw(square);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, this is the result I get. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkPfF.png

Since posting this issue, I've realized that the problem is that when the title bar is enabled, it takes up space on my window, (0, 0) is behind the title bar.  I still don't know how to fix it, though.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please?

Comment: @nvoigt, Sure, I added it to the post.

Comment: As you noticed yourself, testing with unicolor sprites is not effective to draw correct conclusions. I guess someone has already written a collection of sprites specially crafted for testing purposes, like off-by-one errors, scaling issues, transparency rounding errors, and so on.

Comment: There is probably a Windows API call to get dimensions of the taskbar, but it seems like something SFML would be taking into account. Are you using their binaries or did you maybe miss a preprocessor option?

Comment: @Prodigle, thanks for the help.  Unfortunately I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm not sure what you mean.  How would I go about finding out if I'm using their binaries or missing a preprocessor option?